# Xubuntu/XFCE: Is it possible to have email notification in the system tray?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, notification

The title says it all. I want to be notified in the tray.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had to install the package xfce-mailwatch-plugin.

Comment: You   should have accepted Mich's answer instead. Yours adds nothing to the question.

Answer (score 13):

Install `xfce4-mailwatch-plugin`. Then, right click on the panel, and choose Panel --> Add New Items

[image]

Click on Mail Watcher, and then on Add, and Close

[image]

Once done you'll see the icon on the panel.

[image]

Once done, right click on the icon, and choose properties, to be able to setup emails.

[image]

Comment: There is no mail watcher in my list of installable items. Maybe I forgot to install a certain package?

Comment: Which Xubuntu release are you using?

Comment: The latest 13.10.

Comment: Same here.  Try running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: My distro is up-to-date!

Comment: Which Xfce version do you have?  See if you have the plugin installed.

Comment: @ubuplex It seems that this answer (once you install `xfce4-mailwatch-plugin`) solves your problem. Please click on the `accept` button to accept it.

Comment: this doesnt show any kind of preview tho

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Thunderbird, then there is the [Firetray](https://addons.mozilla.org/cs/thunderbird/addon/firetray/) extension.

When there's no unread email, it show the faded envelope icon (that can be configured otherwise). When there are unread emails, it shows their count.

Comment: I use 'minimize to try revived' & 'minimize on start and close' for thunderbird

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the answers given here, first get `xfce4-mailwatch-plugin` then configure the options to get notifications as well.

[image]

For notifications, put the following in the `Run on new messages` field:

```
notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/Adwaita/scalable/actions/mail-mark-important-symbolic.svg "New Mail"
```

[image]

Infact for a more seamless interaction, run the mail client when you click on the icon, by putting the following in `Run on click`:

```
thunderbird
```

You can use whichever email client you want of course.

Comment: Excellent. Works on XFCE debian.

Answer (score 1):

you can add to panel the xfce4-mailwatch
and configure the mailboxes.
email-notification:
(check if libnotify-bin is installed)
properties>external programs>run on new messages: notify-send -i xfce-newmail "New email" "You have new email"

Answer (score 0):

If you want popups containing sender and subject, I suggest you do

```
sudo apt-get install mail-notification
```

[image: mail-notification in xfce4 panel]

Second item from the left. ("3 new mails")

It might look buggy at first, but it's not really: If there is no icon in the panel, it is most probably running anyway but only pops up on a newly received mail.

You can choose between desktop default popup and a messagebox. Plays a sound on incoming mail.

[image: mail-notification popup]